# How to remove "NOT LOGGED IN" value

Tags: magento2, customer-group

I'm using **magento 2.1.**
I would like to make the customer select his customer group while ordering process.

But being a guest and doing an order when he is in checkout and types in his data, the customer group drop down ( I've added ) displays the **"NOT LOGGED IN"** value also - as the guest user is not logged in. 
How can I make this value not shown for all front end forms?
For a customer who wants to create an account it looks fine, the drop down is not showing the **"NOT LOGGED IN"** value.
I'm talking about data for my drop down which is taken from "customer_group" table in database.